# Как сделать собственное поле ввода в qt qml не используя TextEditor

Tags: c++, qt, gui, qml, текстовый-редактор

В качестве пет проекта хочу написать небольшой тестовый редактор(поупражняться именно с алгоритмами редактирования текста, такими как греп буффер, список строчек и тд...). Данное действо я хотел бы сделать с помощью qml qt. Я знаю что qt предоставляет свой отличный текстовый редактор в виде TextEdit, но меня интересует использование именно своих веллосипедов. Я совсем новичок в qt и не представляю как сделать графическую часть, т.е отображение символов, коретки и тд, вобщем то той графической части, которая уже есть в TextEdit и. TextArea. Буду рад любыми источникам, в том числе и ссылкам на исходники TextEdit(не нашел их), и прочей информации по этой теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться QQuickPaintedItem или QQuickItem

Тут есть полное описание и примеры использования
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html